# Twitter - Status is a duplicate code - 187 - But Isn't

Tags: twitter

Using the Twitter REST API, I occasionally see this error,

```
Status is a duplicate code - 187
```

But the status is not a duplicate, I searched for any similar posts in the feed, and there are not any.  Any idea why Twitter would throw this?  The tweet does contain a link.

Answer (score 2):

The standard [Twitter Search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview) only goes back 7 days and then only returns a relevant set of tweets, where the definition of "relevant" is undefined. It's possible that the duplicate was over 7 days old.